# Does Visual Studio conceal some details of execution environment of c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am very new to c#.I started c# today.I don't know execution environment of c# very well.
I can explain my question more by taking netbeans as example.
When we create JSP project in Netbeans then it creates web.xml by itself.
This file is needed to deploy the project.So if we want to create JSP program without using netbeans then we have to create web.xml by ourself.
So my question is does VS also create files by itself that are very neccessary to run C#  program?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save to a *hello.cs* file:

```
class P { static void Main() { System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World"); } }
```

then from a command prompt in the folder of hello.cs do:

```
%Frameworkdir%\v4.0.30319\csc.exe hello.cs
```

If you haven't done errors, you have compiled your first program. You don't need Visual Studio to do it.

So, yes, Visual Studio clearly generates all the files needed to compile a simple program (even a complex one, if you direct it correctly), considering that a .cs file is in truth all you need.

What Visual Studio 2012 generates for a console program is:

- a solution and a project file (that are used to organize your source code and remember references to libraries)
- a configuration file, (not necessary, but Visual Studio 2012 adds it just to write that the program will run on .NET 4.5)
- your source code program
- another source code program (`AssemblyInfo.cs`) so you can add copyright/other metainformations to your exe.
- some random files that Visual Studio uses as cache (the .suo files)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are speaking only of ASP.NET C# execution, since you mention `web.xml` for Java. There is a `web.config` that is probably very comparable to that, since I am not a Java developer I really do not know.

The `web.config` is actually XML and it contains things like connection string to the database, HTTP modules, HTTP handlers, custom application settings that go above and beyond what is part of the core .NET Framework.

The difference lies in that this is not a unit of deployment, like it sounds the `web.xml` is in Java, but rather `web.config` is a run-time explanation of settings that the web server (IIS) uses properly run the application.

Comment: thanks ,but my question is when we create console application in c#.Actually I don't know anything about ASP.NET .When we create C# console application does it related to ASP.NET in any way?

Comment: No, a console application does not use a `web.config` that is related only to ASP.NET, but the console application has an `app.config` that serves a similar purpose of holding settings, but again it is not a deployment manifest.